# <Hopeless>, <Discouraged> and <Disappointed>

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Let's assume that a person feels really down after a failure and now he's severely suffering from the situation they're in.

How each sentences below changes the meaning of my context?

> Be hopeful Jerry! You're my friend! I want your own good! Not only now, but......................

1) don't be hopeless 
2) don't ever get discouraged 
3) don't ever get disappointed

I know that #3 is not natural in this sense, but I wonder why?

According to the dictionaries:

Discouraged --> no longer having the confidence you need to continue doing something

Disappointed --> unhappy because someone or something was not as good as you hoped or expected, or because something did not happen

So, they both should work here in a very similar meaning; although I have no idea how can I distinguish between these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *Don't be discouraged* and *Don't be disappointed* are perfectly natural things to say, and in many contexts they'll effectively mean the same thing - speaker is advising someone to [look on the bright side](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-on-the-bright-side) *(to find good things in a bad situation)*.

As OP has discovered, the *dictionary* definitions are somewhat different, but they're obviously closely related. A "defeatist" reaction to finding yourself in a bad situation might include either or both of ***disappointment*** and ***discouragement***, but in practice using either word will often imply the other anyway.

---

But if we include an "intensifier" like ***ever / never***, there's a good reason why ***Don't ever be disappointed*** is far less likely advice than ***Don't ever be discouraged***.

When you're ***already*** in some specific "bad situation" to which you're reacting negatively (disappointment **and/or** discouragement), people may quite naturally advise you to ***change your reaction*** (often, you can't change the situation itself, just your reaction to it).

But when ***ever / never*** is included in the utterance, it's non-specific "lifetime advice". And the obvious way to avoid ever being discouraged is to have more courage / faith / optimism (as a positive *permanent* aspect of your character, not just a reaction to a specific situation).

On the other hand, the most obvious way to avoid ever being disappointed (through some permanent aspect of your character) is to be a life-long pessimist (never [get your hopes up](https://www.idiomeanings.com/get-ones-hopes-up/) in the first place). But being a pessimist is generally thought of as a *negative* character attribute, so people won't often advise you to go down that path.

---

In any specific situation, you might avoid disappointment by putting in a lot of effort to ensure nothing goes wrong. But as "lifetime advice" that approach won't mean you'll ***never*** be disappointed, because lots of bad situations are unforeseeable and/or unpreventable. Clearly it makes a difference whether someone's advising you to change your reaction to a *specific* situation, or to avoid *ever* having that reaction.

In short, permanently avoiding *discouragement* implies being courageous / resolute (good attribute), whereas permanently avoiding *disappointment* implies lacking hope / ambition (bad attribute).

---

Note that idiomatic ***You're hopeless***! doesn't mean ***You lack optimism*** - it means ***You're useless***!

Comment: Therefore @FumbleFingers "Don't be hopeless" would be wrong, because it means "don't be useless". Right?

Comment: However, though I read your answer two times, but unfortunately, I did nit understand why "don't ever get disappointed" doesn't work, while "don't ever get discouraged" works? I wonder if you could simplify your answer a bit. ;)

Comment: @A-friend: Perhaps I should try getting the point across in a comment first. Suppose someone advises you to avoid ***ever*** being disappointed. I think that implies *You should try be the kind of person to whom disappointment never happens*, which in my book equates to *You should never have any hopes; that way you won't be disappointed when they fail to materialise*. Which is pretty pessimistic / pointless advice, I'd say. Whereas if they advise you to avoid ever being discouraged, they're effectively advising you to ***always*** have hope (don't give up). Is that any clearer?

Comment: Well, @FumbleFinfers, tha only think I understand is that although the word family **"Discouragement/discouraged/discouraging/discourage" are all talking about "losing hope"** (which is exactly the meaning in my question), but they are not used in this sense in English; (at least within my provided context). In the contrary, although **"discouragement/discouraged/discouraging/discourage" are not talking about "losing hope"**, but the "discouragement" word family is used in this sense in English.

Comment: I don't think this is anything particularly to do with how *English* works, except insofar as maybe some other languages don't distinguish *disappointment* from *discouragement* very clearly. In English there can be a clear distinction between being disappointed (something didn't work, so you might try a different approach) and being discouraged (something didn't work, so you just gave up). But in practice, *Don't be disappointed / discouraged / sad / downhearted / etc.* are all often just equivalent to *Be cheerful / positive / optimistic*.

Comment: Just not to be forgotten, you didn't answer my first wuestion in the comments @FumbleFingers. :) Please let me know about "don't be hopeless". Would it sound unnatural in this sense? Does it only mean: "don't be useless". Right? ;)

Comment: @A-friend: For ***BrE*** speakers (but not necessarily all ***AmE*** speakers, I'm not sure) today, ***hopeless*** almost always means *awful, useless, incompetent*. So whereas *Don't lose / give up hope* is encouraging, *You're hopeless* is dismissive. Note that *Don't be hopeless* isn't very idiomatic as it stands - same as *Don't be useless!*, which would be very uncommon compared to *You're useless!*